# Adding client field in django ORM

Tags: python, django, authorization, django-registration

I have an existing app written using  django framework.
This app is using  django-registration-redux to identify the users.The app is using ORM to work with db.

I have  to share the app for  more then 1 client.(to make it SaaS)

I am adding a client field in every table and want to have every user assigned to certain only one client.So even if same DB is used different users that belong to 2 different clients will have totally encapsulated data set from each other.

Is there any existing package that can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [django-tenant-schemas](https://github.com/bernardopires/django-tenant-schemas).

It should solve your problem.